# How to understand _Function_class_(name) in C++

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++, annotations

I am reading some VC++ code and see some usage of this function annotation `_Function_class_(name)`.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159529.aspx):

> The name parameter is an arbitrary string that is designated by the user. It exists in a namespace that is distinct from other namespaces. A function, function pointer, or—most usefully—a function pointer type may be designated as belonging to one or more function classes.

However, I still couldn't understand in what scenario this should be used, and what exactly it means to a function. Can someone please explain a bit more?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This annotation allows you to restrict the set of functions that may be used in a given context.  Generally, when using pointers to functions and references to functions, you can bind those pointers and references to refer to any function that has the correct type.

There may be cases where you want only a restricted set of functions of that type to be usable in a given context, or you may want to ensure that someone really, really means to use a particular function in that context.  For example, if you take a pointer to a callback function, and there are restrictions on what may be done inside of that callback, you might use this attribute to help developers to think about those restrictions when passing new functions as callbacks.

Consider the following example:  `f` is annotated as being of the `special_fp_type` class of functions.  `g` is of the same type, so it is usable in the same contexts as `f`, but it is not annotated as being of the `special_fp_type` class of functions:

```
#include <sal.h>

typedef _Function_class_(special_fp_type) void (*special_fp_type)();

void _Function_class_(special_fp_type) f() { }
void g() { }

void call_special_function(special_fp_type) { }

int main()
{
    call_special_function(f);
    call_special_function(g);
}
```

If you compile this with `/analyze`, you'll get a helpful warning for the usage of `g` here, telling you that it was not part of the expected class of functions:

> warning C28023: The function being assigned or passed should have a `_Function_class_` annotation for at least one of the class(es) in: '`special_fp_type`':
>
> Frequently, when only one function class is in use, this is caused by not declaring a callback to be of the appropriate type.

Comment: So how do you make the warning go away?